# Adding active class to tabs from onclick button event

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm trying to understand the onclick event but getting confused?

I have a onclick button within a "tab" content. When I click this onclick button it opens the correct tab labeled "Tokyo" but it does not carry over / add the active class.

My button within the first tab content is:

```
<button class="new-btn" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Click Me</button>
```

I don't understand how to tell it to do the same onclick event but add the active class to the "Tokyo" tab from this new button click?

Here is the full code:

```
<style>
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
</style>
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
  <button class="new-btn" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Click Me</button>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>
```

Comment: Hi isherwood - thanks for reply. I'm still a little unclear as to what this would look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the active class to your button instead of the active tab. You could select the correct active tab by an id or use the tab index instead of a city name.

```
document.getElementById(cityName + "-tab").classList.add("active");
// evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
```

For example: https://jsfiddle.net/90h5nwds/

Comment: Hi Dakine, thanks for the reply. That worked! Real quick can you explain what + "-tab" means?

Comment: Hi Dakine - I have one more issue. How can I keep the active tab open on page refresh. If the page reloads it always goes to the first tab again. I have a form in second tab and when you hit the submit button it needs to stay on current tab.

Comment: To keep the active tab on refresh you could use URL parameters or give each tab it's own route. For example `?tab=London` or `/cities/london.` `-tab` was needed because the id's of the tab buttons in that fiddle are like this `City-tab`. FYI a JS library/framework like React, Angular or Vue make these things much easier to work with than vanilla JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the clicked button with `event.target`. Then you'll just add your class to it using `classList.add()`. You don't want to set the entire class attribute value with `className` because that wipes out other classes.